# Cross-account subdomain/hosted zone delegation in Route 53 with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-route53

I have two environments and two AWS accounts: dev and prod. Hence, I have two hosted zones:

- dev.example.com in the dev account
- example.com in my prod account

In order to successfully route traffic to my dev.example.com subdomain, I need to delegate to my top-level domain (TLD) with a name server record in my TLD's hosted zone. E.g.,

```
dev.example.com NS Simple [ns-1960.awsdns-22.co.uk. ns-188.awsdns-20.com. ns-208.awsdns-37.net. ns-1089.awsdns-01.org.]
```

In Terraform code, I would define the two hosted zones as such:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "top_level_domain" {
  count = var.env == "prod" ? 1 : 0

  name = "example.com"

  tags = {
    name = "Hosted Zone for top-level domain in production"
    env  = var.env
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "subdomain" {
  count = var.env == "prod" ? 0 : 1

  name = "dev.example.com"

  tags = {
    name = "Hosted Zone for ${var.env} environment"
    env  = var.env
  }
}
```

In the interests of keeping everything codified, I would like to be able to define my delegation record in Terraform configuration. E.g.,

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "subdomain_delegation" {
  count = var.env == "prod" ? 1 : 0

  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.top_level_domain.zone_id
  name    = "dev.example.com"
  type    = "NS"
  ttl     = 300
  records = [
    aws_route53_zone.subdomain.name_servers
  ]
}
```

The issue lies in the `aws_route53_zone.subdomain` resource not existing in my Terraform state for the prod environment (and so `aws_route53_zone.subdomain.name_servers`) cannot be found.

Is there an elegant way to solve this? Or is this just a fact of life if one chooses to use AWS accounts for physical environment separation?

#### Update

The folder structure for my Terraform configuration roughly resembles:

```
dns/ (Terraform module)
dev/ (makes use of module)
prod/ (makes use of module)
```

Comment: You want to have both zones anyway?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to keep both zones (in keeping with the one-environment-per-account pattern that I've been following).

Comment: And that is inside the same codebase?

Comment: Yes, all within the same codebase but different subdirectories for the different environments.

Comment: If you want project separation, then you will have separate Terraform HCL. One for the production zone and one for the delegated zone. Do not try to mix them together as that requires permissions in both accounts which defeats the purpose of separation.

Comment: @JohnHanley I wholeheartedly disagree! IMHO, one of the real benefits of infrastructure as code is being able to create near-identical, consistent environments (with minor variations due to prod/non-prod considerations achieved through parameterised, environment-specific vartiables).

Comment: @BlairNangle - Then how would you keep the DNS resource records separate for dev and production without granting permissions to one group for both groups?  I did not say anything about not using IaaC. If separation is not required, then there are few reasons to use a delegated zone for dev. Subdomains will work just fine.

Comment: @JohnHanley unless I've misunderstood how DNS/Route 53 works, in order to route traffic to my subdomain, I need to delegate to my TLD using a NS record like the example above. My question concerns how to do this (or if it is even possible) with just Terraform.

Comment: @BlairNangle Your assumption is incorrect. Subdomains do not need to be delegated. There are benefits and drawbacks. In most cases just use subdomains. That will make your HCL much simpler to manage. However, for separation/isolation, use delegation. If you are putting everything under one Terraform project, then you have no separation/isolation, so use subdomains.

Comment: @JohnHanley it is only one Terraform project in a Git/folder sense. The configuration for each environment is separately applied via a CI/CD pipeline.

I think this answer explains the need for delegation to the parent domain well: https://serverfault.com/a/817807/425318

Comment: I know Michael. Noting in his answer counters what I have recommended.

Comment: You cannot create a delegated zone using the technique in your question. A delegated zone's name server resource records exist in the parent. That means there is a dependency between the parent zone and the delegated zone. When you create the parent zone you also create the delegated zone. You cannot create the delegated zone without the parent. The resource records of the delegated zone can be managed separately.

Comment: Another item, you do not specify the name servers as a list. The name servers are chosen for you so you would reference them from the managed zone resource.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I'm currently using is to have [two providers](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.1.x/configuration-0-11/providers).

I have a master IAM user which can assume role in sub accounts.

That way - in one terraform script - I can target some actions to the root account alias, then other actions can be targeted to the sub-account alias.

So this allows some sharing of state between multiple accounts within one terraform module.